# Excel calculated field of values within same column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So i have a data, contains a few header, Date, type and Amount
Now "Type" column has a few options including "Bill", "Expenses", "Invoice"

I want to set up a Pivot table and chart that displays the Expenses (Addition of Bill and Expenses) and Revenue (Invoice)

So upon creating the pivot table and filtering the fields to what i am interested in, i have this
[image]

I am trying to create a calculated field that sums up the Bills and Expenses into a new column called "Expenses" so i can have something like this..

[image]

I can not just straight sum Bill + Expenses are they are not individual fields, but filtered values from type field..

I wrote this but gives me zero
=IF(Type="Bill", Amount, 0) + IF(Type="Expenses", Amount, 0)

Can anybody help.

Comment: You need a calculated **item** not a calculated field.

Answer (score 0):

So, just use a calculation like:

=sum(b3,c3)

assuming Bills is column B and Expenses column C.

I avoid Powerpivot or Chartwizard etc as they often don't do the more complicated stuff..